follow docker get-started tutorial but see error connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.5:3306
I follow docker tutorial here
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/introduction/develop-with-containers/
and follow the step in Home > Get started > Introduction > Develop with containers,
docker compose watch
then open the browser http://localhost
but no expected Hello World screen, in dokcer desktop I see following error messages

Waiting for mysql:3306............  Timeout  Error: connect
ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.5:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1607:16) {    errno: -111,    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',    syscall: 'connect',
address: '172.18.0.5',    port: 3306,    fatal: true  }  [nodemon] app
crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

what is the problem and how to solve now?
